# String.Format() - How to use a variable that contains your formatting?

Tags: vb.net, string.format

In vb.net, I am attempting to format a string into a formatted Phone Number where the formatting is read in from a database variable.

A phone number like "5555555555" will get nicely formated into "(555) 555-5555" if the string is formatted in this fashion:

```
String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", Long.Parse(PhoneNum))
```

However, the "(###) ###-####" string is stored in a database, to maintain a central formatting choice for phone numbers in a theoretical system.

Does anyone know how I can substitute this hardcoded formatting for one with a variable?  I am trying something like:

```
Dim phoneFormat as String = <~read in the String format from DB~>
String.Format("{0:" & phoneFormat.ToString & "}", Long.Parse(PhoneNum)))
```

Unfortunately however, this only returns the string itself.  I am presented with "(###) ###-####".

Comment: Substitute `phoneFormat` with another format? Btw, `String.Format` **returns** a string: `Dim result = String.Format(...)`

Comment: Does your  phoneFormat coming from the database possibly have single quotes in it? That would give the results you are speaking about.

Comment: `Long.Parse(PhoneNum).ToString(phoneFormat)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.ToString` is probably simpler, but you can still use `String.Format`. Here are these two methods

```
Dim phoneNum = "1234567890"
Dim phoneFormat = "(###) ###-####"
' simpler version using Long.ToString
Dim formattedPhoneNumber1 = Long.Parse(phoneNum).ToString(phoneFormat)
' your original attempt using String.Format
Dim formattedPhoneNumber2 = String.Format("{0:" & phoneFormat & "}", Long.Parse(phoneNum))
' cleaner version using String.Format with traditional interpolation and $ interpolation
Dim formattedPhoneNumber3 = String.Format($"{{0:{phoneFormat}}}", CLng(phoneNum))
Console.WriteLine(formattedPhoneNumber1)
Console.WriteLine(formattedPhoneNumber2)
Console.WriteLine(formattedPhoneNumber3)
Console.ReadLine()
```

> (123) 456-7890
>   (123) 456-7890
>   (123) 456-7890

I think what you were probably not sending the Long into the function, rather the string (by the way why is the number 5555555555 being stored as a string in the first place?). You need to include `Long.Parse()` otherwise the `#`s in your format won't know what to operate on.

Comment: Interpolated: `String.Format($"{{0:{phoneFormat}}}", CLng(phoneNum))`. Well, all right...

Comment: @Jimi added it thanks. Btw I was trying to include a version with `$` interpolation but couldn't figure it out. I still don't know how the additional curly braces allow for it. But it looks great :)